# How do I iterate through JSON string

Tags: java, json, string

I received a `Json` string as:

```
{"items":[{"score":0.0,"year":0,"id":258}, "score":0.0,"year":0,"id":259}],"id":0}
```

I want to store `ids` in a list, so the result should be:
[258,259].

What's the best efficient to do it? Any suggestion?

Comment: Get any JSON library or parse it manually. Extract what you want and collect it into an array.

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Answer (score 1):

Using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

```
List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();

JsonArray items = new JsonParser()
   .parse(myString)
   .getAsJsonObject()
       .getAsJsonArray("items");

for (JsonElement item : items) {
    ids.add(item
        .getAsJsonObject()
        .getAsJsonPrimitive("id")
        .getAsInt());
}
```

Comment: I got this error onstructor JSONParser in class jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.JSONParser cannot be applied to given types.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
      items: [
        {
              score:0.0,
              year:0,
              id:258
            },
        {
            score:0.0,
            year:0,
            id:259
       }],
       id:0};

var items = obj.items;

items = items.map( function(el) { return el.id;});

console.log( JSON.stringify(items));
```

Comment: Wrong language.